# Setting font requires size that overrides sizeToFit() Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, fonts, font-size

I am making a label, and trying to set the font to "Avenir" like this:

```
    let usernameLabel: UILabel
    usernameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: third * screenHeight + sixth * screenHeight, width: third * screenWidth, height: 30))
    usernameLabel.text = "Username"
    usernameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 30) // Where I set the font
    usernameLabel.sizeToFit()
    usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray()
    self.view.addSubview(usernameLabel)
```

However I want the size to adjust dynamically using usernameLabel.sizeToFit(), however this has not effect as I have to set a size when setting the font, and if I try not to use the size option, it returns an error.

Comment: Try [usernameLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to scale the font to fit the frame size.

So replace:

```
usernameLabel.sizeToFit()  // Modify the frame to fit the label
```

With:

```
usernameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true // Modify the font size to fit the frame
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```
let str = "your string" as NSString

    if let font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 30) {

        let size  = str.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : font])

        label.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, size.width, height)
        label.text = "your string"
    }
```